# Retrieve ComboBox DropDown Data with ADODB Connection

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, combobox, adodb

I am in a very big trouble. I developed an application in VB.NET which stores all its data in an Access database. The access file is stored on a network location.

The application works perfectly fine on my computer. However, on other computers it doesn't work properly.

The ComboxBox retrieves its data on its DropDown event from the access file. This works fine on my computer but on other computers, the ComboxBox doesn't extract anything from the DB. It doesn't throw any error though. The other computer has access to the network location also.

If I store it on other computer's Desktop then it runs fine but problem occures when I store the DB on a network location. on My computer, the network location also works fine.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Sounds like your connection string is not set up correctly. Show us your DB connection string...

Answer (score 0):

I figured. Although user had read/write access to that network location. But, the particular DB file's owner was only me. I got in touch with my internal IT team who helped me to everyone have access to that file.